# How can I limit user access to transaction SOST?

Tags: email, authorization, abap, sap-basis

I am trying to limit a SAP user´s access to transaction SOST. He may only have read/display permissions. I have tried to limit the authorizations in a role using the authorization objects S_TCODE, S_DATASET, S_OC_ROLE and S_OC_SEND. But it is not sufficient.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can check at SU24 the objects related to SOST TCode. I think this ones may be the ones you're looking for:

S_OC_DOC; S_OC_ROLE; S_OC_SEND; S_OC_SOSG; S_OC_TCD

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **SOSG** transaction instead. This transaction corresponds to transaction SOST but makes additional authorization checks.
I'd rather do the above requirement in this way:

1. Give to user authorization to T-code SOSG (via S_TCODE authorization object)
2. Create separate user group and add the relevant users to this group
3. Use authorization object S_OC_SOSG where you should strictly specify this group and type of send requests to display

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [**PFCG**](http://www.sapdatasheet.org/abap/tran/PFCG.html) (Role Maintenance) role with authorization field **S_TCODE** to limit the transaction codes could be executed by a user.